# How to reference certain View Controllers

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to reference a UITabController from my app delegate, even though it isn't my rootViewController. How do I do it?

`UITabBarController *tabBarController =
    (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController =
    [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    DocumentsViewController *ViewController =
    [[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];`

I want to change the first line of code so it doesn't reference the "rootViewController" but directly references my UITabBarController, because I have a start screen that I want to use for the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `UITabBarController` in the .h of your `AppDelegate`.

Get a reference to your AppDelegate:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Then you can do:

```
delegate.tabBarController;
```

Or you could do:

```
[(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] tabBarController];
```

Also, make sure to include `"AppDelegate.h"` in your rootViewController/

**EDIT:**

Add this to the `.h` of your `rootViewController` class so that it is publicly accessible:

```
@property SecondViewController *mySecondViewController;
```

Now, when you instantiate your `SecondViewController` before you present it modally make sure to do it like this:

```
self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController ...
```

You should now be able to reference your `secondViewController` from your `AppDelegate` like this:

```
self.rootViewController.mySecondViewController
```

Comment: I don't think I understand, maybe I didn't write clearly enough. The first view in my app is the start screen, and when I click start it brings up my second view, which is from the UITabBarController. I want this same code to function in my app delegate, but instead of referencing the "rootViewController" (which would be my start screen) I want to reference the second view which is the UITabBarController. Am i supposed to reference my app delegate from within my app delegate?

Comment: When you press start in `rootViewController`, do you use a `UINavigationController` to move on to the `secondViewController`?

Comment: So your `secondViewController` contains a `UITabBarController`, and you want to reference `UITabBarController` that's contained in your `secondViewController`?

Comment: I'm sorry if I mixed up the terminology. By second view controller I meant the view controller that is modally connected to my start screen. My "second" view controller is a UITabBarController, and I want to reference it from my app delegate, changing the first line of code there.